# javascript return map with key as empty string

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bundle-layout

In D3, the [edge bundling example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1044242), we have this code

```
// Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
function packageHierarchy(classes) {
  var map = {};

  function find(name, data) {
    var node = map[name], i;
    if (!node) {
      node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
      if (name.length) {
        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
        node.parent.children.push(node);
        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
      }
    }
    return node;
  }

  classes.forEach(function(d) {
    find(d.name, d);
  });

  return map[""];
}
```

I can't figure out what `return map[""];` means. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each class it's given, it works recursively back through the parents, taking the class name up to the last `.`, adding each parent to the map as it goes, finally adding a parent with empty string for the name (there was no dot).

This parent is regarded as the root, and has a path of empty string, and this node is what is returned.

I'll try to explain better with an example;

Given a class with the full path `Main.Sub.Class`, the code will add the `Main.Sub.Class` node to the map with that path, and then try to find/create a node for `Main.Sub`, and add itself as a child to this parent node.

If it has to create a new node for `Main.Sub`, it will try to find the parent for this class too, (`Main`), and add `Main.Sub` as a child to `Main`. It then continues up again, but since there is no `.` in the path, the parent path is `""` (empty string).

Since all classes will eventually end up adding themselves as a child to the empty string node, this node can be considered the root node, and so is the node to be returned.

Comment: bonus question:) is the 'children' a reserved keyword or can i replace it with anything?

Comment: Erm.. from what I can see of how that's being used, I think it has to be called `'children'` because the root gets passed to `d3.layout.cluster()` which I think expects to have the `children` property on each of the nodes. Not entirely sure though, I've never looked at d3 before..

Comment: However, looking further on, I've seen this in the documentation; https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout#children. I think that should allow you to override the function for retrieving the children from a given node, that would have to be called on the `cluster` variable. So changing the definition of the `cluster` variable to something like this; http://pastebin.com/rC6ry0nC would allow you to rename the `children` property to `offspring`.